# What did Julieta see at the end of "The Son"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-son

I have watched The Son (el hijo) on Netflix. Can anyone please explain its ending?

I am clear till the end, but what did Julieta see in Sigrid's place? The camera just zoomed into her face, with a kid crying in the background and then the end credits rolled. What is the backstory of Sigrid, is there a sequel? Or did the director just leave it to the audience to predict the end?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen it myself, but according to [distractify](https://www.distractify.com/p/the-son-netflix-ending-explained):

> The movie ends in this open-ended way, allowing viewers to interpret
>   for themselves what all went down with Sigrid and Gudrum, and how they
>   let Lorenzo take the fall for their twisted antics.
>
> Whether it's a case of Munchausen-by-proxy is unknown, although all
>   signs do point in that direction.